# Google Maps v3 Changing Marker's Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I want to change a Marker's map on-the-fly. Specifically, I have three collections of different markers, so I'm building them all with an undefined map, then trying to set their map property when I switch between the collections. It isn't working- the markers only display when passed a map in the constructor.

```
//Build a new marker with no map
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    title: el.name + " #" + el.location_id,
    map: null
});
markers[el.location_id] = marker;

//Later, when displaying
$.each(markers, function(i, marker){
    marker.map = map;
});
//Marker doesn't show up.
```

Further, when I create a marker, then remove its map, it still displays:

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pos,
    title: el.name + " #" + el.location_id,
    map: map
});
marker.map = null;
//Marker is still on the map...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the Marker object's map setter method, i.e.:

```
$.each(markers, function(i, marker){
    marker.setMap(map);
});
```

Setting the map to null should remove it from any map on which the Marker object is displayed.

See the [methods](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#Marker) section under the v3 documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setMap() method of the Marker so in your case

```
marker.setMap(map)
```

To remove a marker:

```
marker.setMap(null)
```